# Number Frequencies

Tags: mysql, frequency

I need an sql query to merge-up all numbers I have on my table on different columns and find the sum of their occurrence.

My table structure is like this

```
id | Pick1 | Pick2 | Pick3 | Pick4 | Pick5 | Pick6 |
----------------------------------------------------
 1 | 1     |  23   |  56   |  56   |   78  |  89   |
----------------------------------------------------
 2 | 9     |  49   |  90   |  56   |   78  |  89   |
----------------------------------------------------
 3 | 2     |  65   |  56   |  56   |   78  |  89   |
----------------------------------------------------
 4 | 1     |  23   |  23   |  56   |   78  |  89   |
```

Expected Result

```
Number | Frequency
-------------------
  23   |  5
-------------------
  56   |  7
-------------------
  89   |  4
....
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to union all records using `UNION ALL` in a subquery. Try this one,

```
SELECT x.a `Number`, 
       COUNT(x.a) `Frequency`
FROM
(
    SELECT Pick1 a
    FROM TableNAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Pick2 a
    FROM TableNAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Pick3 a
    FROM TableNAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Pick4 a
    FROM TableNAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Pick5 a
    FROM TableNAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Pick6 a
    FROM TableNAME
) x
GROUP BY x.a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pick AS `Number`,
       COUNT(1) AS Frequency
FROM(
     SELECT Pick1 AS pick
     FROM table_name
     UNION ALL
     SELECT Pick2 AS pick
     FROM table_name
     SELECT Pick3 AS pick
     FROM table_name
     SELECT Pick4 AS pick
     FROM table_name
     SELECT Pick5 AS pick
     FROM table_name
     SELECT Pick6 AS pick
     FROM table_name
    ) a
 GROUP BY a.pick;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier, if you could re-organize your table into a struture like the following:

```
id | pick | nr
------------------
1    1       1  
1    2      23
1    3      56
```

In such a table, you could easily group and count the numbers.
Would it be possible in your project to change ths table structure like this?

Alternatively, if is not possible, you could create a helper view which arranges the data in this structure, and then you take this result for further processing. Such a view could be constructed by using a UNION of six select statements. Please let me know if you need further assistance on this.